# Elasticsearch throwing an error during startup

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have implemented Elasticsearch in spring boot. On every server restart, I am getting the following error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ps'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'pr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rejecting mapping update to [products] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, product]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar:5.2.0.RELEASE]
```

I have deleted the index every time to start the server and then perform the index. Can anyone suggest to me what will the solution

Comment: are you using Spring Data Elasticsearch? Or just Elasticsearch and build your own queries? Which version of Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use?

Comment: I have upvoted lone back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch v6 and above cannot have more than one type per index. But from your exception, your mapping is trying to create more than one type on an index (_doc and product)

Refer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @Karthick from Elasticsearch 6.X more than one type per index is deprecated and only `_doc` internal and default mapping type is supported till version 7(for backward compatibility purpose) and that too will be completely removed from soon to be released 8.X major version.

**You need to remove your own type name `product` to solve the issue.**

As mentioned in the [official link why it's removed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html#_why_are_mapping_types_being_removed).

> In an Elasticsearch index, fields that have the same name in different
>   mapping types are backed by the same Lucene field internally. In other
>   words, using the example above, the user_name field in the user type
>   is stored in exactly the same field as the user_name field in the
>   tweet type, and both user_name fields must have the same mapping
>   (definition) in both types.
>
> This can lead to frustration when, for example, you want deleted to be
>   a date field in one type and a boolean field in another type in the
>   same index.
>
> On top of that, storing different entities that have few or no fields
>   in common in the same index leads to sparse data and interferes with
>   Lucene’s ability to compress documents efficiently.
>
> For these reasons, we have decided to remove the concept of mapping
>   types from Elasticsearch.